# for loop multiple value

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, xlsxwriter

My script is below:

```
import xlsxwriter
import subprocess

workbook = xlsxwriter.Workbook('demo.xlsx')
worksheet = workbook.add_worksheet('NMOC')
bold = workbook.add_format({'bold': True})

 # Write some data headers.
worksheet.write('A1', 'RNC', bold)
worksheet.write('B1', 'CELL', bold)
for line in open('/root/Desktop/Scripting/Update_Table/eaw/test.txt'):

alias = line.rstrip("\n").split(';')
print(alias)

# Start from the first cell. Rows and columns are zero indexed.
row = 1
col = 0

for rnc, cell in (alist):
   worksheet.write(row,col,  rnc)
   worksheet.write(row,col + 1, cell)
   row += 1
workbook.close()
```

I am using python 3.5 version. This is the error I'm getting :

```
['BSC19', 'TS9001']
['BSC19', 'TS555']
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "test.py", line 53, in <module>
    for rnc, cell in (alias):
ValueError: too many values to unpack (expected 2)
```

What's wrong in my code?

[root@nocjobs eaw]# cat test.txt

```
BSC19;TS9001
BSC19;TS555
```

Comment: What line of code is causing the error?

Comment: my script  updated

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I bet that the problem is here -> `for rnc, cell in (alist):`

Because on some iteration(maybe even the first) var `alist` contains only one value, but you try to unpack it to `tuple(rnc, cell)`.

As I understood, you want to do something like this:

```
row = 1
for line in open('test.txt'):
    alist = line.rstrip("\n").split(';')
    col = 0
    for value in (alist):
        worksheet.write(row, col, value)
        col += 1
    row += 1
```

Answer (score 1):

If you meant `line = "cat myfile BSC19;TS9001 BSC19;TS555"` in your question, then the problem is with what `alist` has this in it, which would be `['cat myfile BSC19', 'TS9001 BSC19', 'TS555']`, which is a list of 3 items.

The `for rnc, cell in (alist):` is like the assignment `rnc, cell = alist` which means that it expects `alist` to have exactly two thing it.

I believe you need fix the `line.rstrip( ).split(';')`, but I'm not sure what the expected format of the data is in teh`testtt.sh` file.